# math is off in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, operator-keyword

I have been trying to set up a simple weight calculator for co-workers.  I know there are plenty on the internet, but I wanted them to enjoy something that came from in house.

I currently am experiencing two problems using my statistics.

My weight is 180 my height is 60 and my age is 42.

I use the current formula age+(6.23 x height)+(12.7 x weight)-(6.76 x age)

the first section should show 1121 but instead calculates 1080
the second section should show 762 but instead calculates 720
the third section should show 284 but instead 252

I also get operand issues or missing operator issues and would ask for a little hope.  Eventually I will include the women's calculation in also and then give it a nice little frontend. Help would be greatly appreciated.

here is my code so far.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:age
Set /p age= What is your age?:  
SET /P ANSWER= you entered %age% is this correct? (Y/N)?  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :weight)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :weight)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={n} (goto :age)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={no} (goto :age)  
:weight  
Set /p weight= What is your weight?:  
SET /P ANSWER= you entered %weight% is this correct? (Y/N)?  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :height)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :height)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={n} (goto :weight)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={no} (goto :weight)  
:height  
Set /p height= What is your Height in Inches?:  
SET /P ANSWER= you entered %height% is this correct? (Y/N)?  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :calcs)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :calcs)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={n} (goto :height)  
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={no} (goto :height)  
:calcs  
set /A calc1= %weight%*6.23  
echo weight = %calc1%  
set /A calc2= %height%*12.7  
echo height = %calc2%  
set /A calc3= %age%*6.76  
set /A calc4= %age%+%calc1%  
echo age = %calc3%  
set /A calc5 = %calc4%+%calc2%  
set /A Result= %calc5%-%calc3%  

echo your caloric intake should be %Result%
```

Comment: Batch math only supports integers.

Comment: Looks like cmd doesn't handle decimals. Do yourself a favor and pick a better language - PowerShell is at least sane and Windows folks seem to like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the `SET /A` command can only manage integer numbers, there are several ways to perform floating point arithmetic operations in Batch files, even trigonometric and logarithms! However, you just need a very simple operation with two decimal places that may be achieved this way:

```
:calcs
set /A Result=( age + height*623 + weight*1270 - age*676 + 50 ) / 100

echo your caloric intake should be %Result%
```

Note that the `+ 50` is equivalent to add 0.5 for rounding the final sum.

Comment: In your description you said "I use the current formula age+(6.23 x height)+(12.7 x weight)-(6.76 x age)". I used this formula, but it seems that you interchange height and weight. Does my solution give right results with the right formula? Or, give it incorrect numeric results? You did not described the exact problem...

Comment: It does not give the correct results but it is the correct math. Its really weird.  I came up with. 2375 but should come up with 1599. But I went back to the model and realized I am dyslexic. I appreciate the help it worked well. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: OK UPdate using setting 180lbs 66inches 42years <br> I set up the equation again like this: set /A Result=( 66 + (%weight%*623) + (%height%*1270) - (%age%*676) + 50 ) / 100    I changed the age at the front of the equation to 66, then moved that to the end + 66 and this worked well.  Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

so the full answer to the question was this.

my original equation used decimals which Aacini pointed out does not work.  So he added the +50 to compensate for the decimal and made them whole numbers.  then divided by 100 at the end removing the two decimal points.

This is the rendition that was sent over that did a better job.

```
set /A Result=( age + height*623 + weight*1270 - age*676 + 50 ) / 100
```

age was replaced with + 66 and moved to the end for proper calcs. May not have needed the extra parenthesis but wanted to be sure.

```
set /A MResult=( (%weight%*623) + (%height%*1270) - (%age%*676) + 50 ) / 100 + 66
```

age (for the women's) was replaced with 655 and moved to the end, this equation worked great.

```
set /A FResult=((%weight%*435) + (%height%*470) - (%age%*470) + 50 ) / 100 + 655
```

Thanks for the help Aacini

Comment: Nor the parentheses neither the percent-signs are needed; you may just write: `set /A MResult=( weight*623 + height*1270 - age*676 + 50 ) / 100 + 66`. For further details, type: `SET /?`.

Comment: Thanks again Aacini, Is there a rule of why they are not required. I thought batch required them?